# Adding column to Rcpp::DataFrame is falling back to list

Tags: r, rcpp

When I add a column to a dataframe using Rcpp it ceases to be rendered as a dataframe once returned. I'm trying to stay as close to the original examples of adding a column as possible, but I get a list regardless of how I mutate it.

As you can see below, I'm losing the class and some important attributes on the object when I add a column either via assigning to a new key or using `push_back()`.

Runnable reprex [here](https://gist.github.com/trestletech/d07fa170b613c5c0107ef000a15ef72e), or output copied below

```r
fun <- Rcpp::cppFunction('
List DataFrameExample() {
  Rcpp::IntegerVector a = {1, 2, 3};

  // create a new data frame
  Rcpp::DataFrame DF = Rcpp::DataFrame::create(
    Rcpp::Named("a1")=a
  );

  Rcpp::DataFrame NDF = clone(DF);

  //NDF.push_back(a, "a2");
  NDF["a2"] = a;

  return(Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("origDataFrame")=DF,
    Rcpp::Named("newDataFrame")=NDF)
  );
}')

dfs <- fun()
dfs
```

```
## $origDataFrame
##   a1
## 1  1
## 2  2
## 3  3
## 
## $newDataFrame
## $newDataFrame$a1
## [1] 1 2 3
## 
## $newDataFrame$a2
## [1] 1 2 3
```

```r
lapply(dfs, class)
```

```
## $origDataFrame
## [1] "data.frame"
## 
## $newDataFrame
## [1] "list"
```

```r
lapply(dfs, attributes)
```

```
## $origDataFrame
## $origDataFrame$names
## [1] "a1"
## 
## $origDataFrame$class
## [1] "data.frame"
## 
## $origDataFrame$row.names
## [1] 1 2 3
## 
## 
## $newDataFrame
## $newDataFrame$names
## [1] "a1" "a2"
```

(R 3.6.0 on Catalina 10.15.1 with Rcpp 1.0.3)

Comment: Rcpp does not really have all that much in terms of data.frame support.  As you saw, it is not too robust either.  So if I were I might bite the bullet and just a write a little that converts to list, add/removes as needed and then re-creates a data.frame.  My go-to idiom is just the `return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(...)` as the last statements.

Comment: Thanks, @DirkEddelbuettel. I actually ended up here because I needed more than the 20 columns that the `create()` template supports. :)

Comment: Ah, yes, known constraint.  The usual trick for that is to nest inside of one or more `Rcpp::List` instances.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately a `Rcpp::DataFrame` object looses its `class` attribute when a new column is added, throwing it back to a `Rcpp::List`. One can verify this in C++ by adding `Rcpp::Rcout << NDF.hasAttribute("class") << std::endl;` before and after adding the new column. Fortunately, it is easy to turn a `Rcpp::List` into a `Rcpp::DataFrame` explicitly:

```r
fun <- Rcpp::cppFunction('
List DataFrameExample() {
  Rcpp::IntegerVector a = {1, 2, 3};

  // create a new data frame
  Rcpp::DataFrame DF = Rcpp::DataFrame::create(
    Rcpp::Named("a1")=a
  );

  Rcpp::DataFrame NDF = clone(DF);
  Rcpp::Rcout << NDF.hasAttribute("class") << std::endl; 
  //NDF.push_back(a, "a2");
  NDF["a2"] = a;
  Rcpp::Rcout << NDF.hasAttribute("class") << std::endl; 

  return(Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("origDataFrame") = DF,
    Rcpp::Named("newDataFrame") = Rcpp::DataFrame(NDF))
  );
}')

dfs <- fun()
#> 1
#> 0
dfs
#> $origDataFrame
#>   a1
#> 1  1
#> 2  2
#> 3  3
#> 
#> $newDataFrame
#>   a1 a2
#> 1  1  1
#> 2  2  2
#> 3  3  3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>