# DataFrame nrows null after adding a column

Tags: r, rcpp

I am using DataFrames in a C++ code that I use in a R package. At some point, I want to add a column of ones at the front of my DataFrame. I do so as follow, where `df` is my DataFrame:

```
df.push_front(NumericVector(df.nrows(), 1.0), "(Intercept)");
```

After this, I expect `df` to contain its column plus a new one full one ones at the beginning. And it seems to be doing that.

But the problem is that now `df.nrows()` is equal to zero, and not what it used to be. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the outcome of ```df.nrows()```? You might be missing the input. Perhaps```df.nrows(df)```? You may also try ```nrows(df)```

Comment: The output of `df.nrows()` is `10000` before I push a column in the front and `0` after. I tried `Rcpp::nrows(df)` and `df.nrows(df)` but none compile, saying that such functions with such arguments do not exist.

This is really weird as I can still access the columns of the dataframe correctly, it is just this `nrows` function that gives the wrong output.

Comment: consider sharing your data using dput() and your desired output so the SO community will be more able to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding column to Rcpp::DataFrame is falling back to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365294/adding-column-to-rcppdataframe-is-falling-back-to-list) As discussed there, adding a column to a `Rcpp::DataFrame` reverts it back to a `Rcpp::List`, which does not have rows. (You'll notice that `.ncol()` still works, but that's because [`.ncol()` just gives you the length](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/95d0854f2102e0a4aaba888e4c312e0b1c015297/inst/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h#L90))

Comment: As a side comment, I think this is likely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Since you're prepending a column of ones, particularly since you're naming it `(Intercept)`, I'm guessing a `Rcpp::DataFrame` is likely not to be the type of data structure that would ultimately be most useful to you...

Comment: I indeed convert the dataframe to a matrix after that, and decided to add the column to that matrix instead of the dataframe. I, however, still find it odd that adding a column to a dataframe makes it fall back to a list... Anyway, thank you for the help!